# How to format all parameters of a function in one line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

My javascript code is formatted like this and I'm not comfortable with this :

```
function(
    req,
    req.session,
    amount,
    offerCode,
    userChoice,
    referenceNo,
    transactionId,
    function (err, res) {
        ...
}
```

I prefer to change it like this :

```
function( req, req.session, amount, offerCode, userChoice, eferenceNo, transactionId, function (err, res) {
    ...
}
```

Is there any code-formatter to do this automatically on a huge bunch of code.

Comment: [Prettier - Code formatter - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)?

Comment: Prettier exactly change one-line parameters to one parameter per line. Is there any setting to change this?

Comment: You can use `"printWidth": whateverCharacterLengthYouWant` in your `.prettierrc` file. After the given character length(plus some other conditions) it will come on next line.By default it is set to `80`

Comment: @DebajitMajumder Shall I add .prettierrc separately? My OS is Ubuntu.18.04

Comment: You can add `.prettierrc` at the root of your project code and you should commit that file so that everyone working on that project follow the same code styling/formatting. `.prettierrc` is a simple JSON file.

Comment: @DebajitMajumder Thanks. It works like a charm. If you want, add your comment as an answer. I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help you. Seems like @PraveenKumarPurushothaman just answered the same what I have mentioned here in comment. You can accept his answer and upvote my comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing to use is [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) in this case. Use a file called `.prettierrc` in your root of the folder that you put into VS Code and add the following inside it:

```
{
  "printWidth": 8000
}
```

The default is `80` in this case.